# How to say putting knee on a table

Tags: word-choice, expressions

What I am doing in that picture? I couldn’t describe it in English?

[image]

In the attached picture, you will see my leg, my knee is on  the table.

Images are not visible I think. I put my knee to the left side of the table when I was sitting on a chair. Is this leaning against?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "up against" the table - there isn't really a common idiom

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I will say, I put my knee up against the table.

Comment: Yes, putting knee "on" the table would suggest on top, "up against" suggests leaning as in the picture

Comment: You are leaning your knee against the desk.

Comment: "I rested my knee on the edge of the table."

Comment: "I propped my knee on the edge of the table."